# How to find out if a dependency property is bound to a readonly property?

Tags: wpf, binding, dependency-properties

I defined an user control and a dependency property (called: Text).
Now I want to know if the bound property of Text is readonly? (in code behind)

I did not find an entry in the BindingExpression.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You won't be able to create a TwoWay or OneWayToSource binding to a read-only property. So what's your point?

Comment: I want to find it out to set the readonly flag of an internal TextEdit.

Comment: It is part of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33502384/wpf-textbox-with-ellipsis-trimming-and-validation-adorner

Comment: If you have an idea to solve my other question please help.

Comment: It does not help. The Mode is default in case of a two way binding.

Comment: When Mode is `Default` you know that the binding is TwoWay because you have set BindsTwoWayByDefault. In that case setting a Binding to a readonly property will throw an InvalidOperationException.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example we can make something like this:

```
// create some control
var elem = new FrameworkElement();
// create context for control
elem.DataContext = new TestClass();
// create binding
var bind = elem.SetBinding(UIElement.AllowDropProperty, "ReadOnlyBool");
// we can resolve property
var pi = bind.ResolvedSource.GetType().GetProperty(bind.ResolvedSourcePropertyName);
// and check if it writeable
var isReadOnly = pi.CanWrite;
```

Not every BindingExpression has ResolvedSource and/or ResolvedSourcePropertyName, so, i suppose, it reason why we have not information about resolved property.

Context:

```
public class TestClass : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyPropertyKey ReadOnlyBoolProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly("ReadOnlyBool", typeof (bool), typeof (TestClass),
            new PropertyMetadata());

    public bool ReadOnlyBool => (bool) GetValue(ReadOnlyBoolProperty.DependencyProperty);
}
```